# How to write k8s NetworkPolicy to deny trafic from pod to pod?

Tags: networking, kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

i'ams truggle with writing K8s network policy to deny trafic from pod to pod, pod must be specefied by label or name.

Can some one help me?

I'am not are devops/sys admin. And i need this for Integration Testting.
I check https://github.com/ahmetb/kubernetes-network-policy-recipes examples. But still can't do it.

Here is exampel that allow acces from only one service

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: api-allow
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: bookstore
      role: api
  ingress:
  - from:
      - podSelector:
          matchLabels:
            app: bookstore
```

But i need oposite things, denny only from one pod.

Comment: Are you looking for `deny all` sort of network policy? usually people will define one policy that denies all pod connections by default and then they will allow only selected pods to communicate.

Comment: Usually yes,
But i need allow ALL, But denny ONLY SPECIFIC list.

Comment: Then just do the opposite. like for allow all https://github.com/ahmetb/kubernetes-network-policy-recipes/blob/master/05-allow-traffic-from-all-namespaces.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should define two network policies as mentioned below

1. default deny all traffic
2. allow the traffic to a  pod from other pods/namespaces

here are some good recipes that would be helpful. follow the link
[network policy recipes](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubernetes-network-policy-recipes)